# FragmentTransaction adding fragment instead of replace

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building an QR Code Scanner using gms Vision API. The scanner is working properly, but as soon as I try to replace the fragment, it's not getting replaced, it's getting added.

Code to replace:

```
val manager: FragmentManager? = (context as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager
val transaction: FragmentTransaction? = manager?.beginTransaction()
transaction?.replace(R.id.container, ScannedFragment())
transaction?.addToBackStack(null)
transaction?.commit()
```

There are no error messsages. The app looks like this then:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgms6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself. I had to use a FrameLayout to replace.